# Millisecond precise timestamp field in DynamoDB stream

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table where I enabled DynamoDB stream. I also have a trigger which invokes Lambda function when item is changed.

Is there any millisecond-precise timestamp field in DynamoDB stream I can rely on?

I'd like to rely on it in downstream services which are sensitive to the order of messages.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, the `ApproximateCreationDateTime` on the stream is, as its name suggests, not all that accurate. If you need order I would use the `SequenceNumber`, which is in order. If you must have a timestamp you'll have to include it in your data, but be aware that the time you create the timestamp in your data is not the same as when the data is added to the table. In many cases that's fine, but if you have more than one process writing you could have process A created a timestamp that is before process B, but the data from B could be written to the table before the data from A.

Comment: Sequence number is unique per partition-key within its shard. Every partition has its own shard. Partitions can be split because of 10GB limit. This indicates to me that there is some chance of sequence number conflict in downstream services. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. There isn’t anything that is going to guarantee order across partition keys. You can look at the partition key and sequence number to get ordering within a partition.

Comment: Will sequence number be always unique for the same partition key?

Comment: The sequence number is unique and always increasing (though not always by 1).

Comment: Are sequence numbers unique only for 24 hours?